# Javascript: Are callback functions the only ones allowed to refer to outside variables in a forward-looking way?

Tags: javascript, callback, closures

I have the following code, note that in the callback function for the `close` event, the reference to the variable `ConnectingLine`, which comes after the callback itself:

```
$('.tabs').tabs({
    close: function(event, ui) {
        ConnectingLine.show();
    }
});

var ConnectingLine = MyHelpers.connectingLine({options here...});
```

I was assuming that this kind of referencing would work for any kind of closure, but it turns out to be not true. For example:

```
var add = (function () {
    return function () {return counter += 1;}
    var counter = 7;
})();

function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = add();
}
```

The above code would break, causing a NaN error. Apparently, the definition needs to be **before** the closure function referring to it.

My question is, what allows the callback function to refer to outside variables in a forward-looking manner? Is this really unique to callback functions only? Thanks.

Comment: Think the problem is that `counter` inside the returned function is `undefined`, so you are trying to add `1` to `undefined`, which will give you `NaN`. That is because you have to declare `counter` before the `return` statement, otherwise it can't be reached. `counter` does not have to be declared before the returned function, but anything after `return` will not be executed.

Comment: @DavidDomain, yes I agree your point, but think that by the time the closure function is actually executed, the counter is already changed from undefined to some numeric value. The same for my first callback example, isn't it? That's what I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Control never reaches

```
var counter = 7;
```

Therefore your maths uses an `undefined` value (`counter` is declared and available for use because it is hoisted). The `+=` operator coerces `undefined` to `NaN` and `NaN` is toxic.

Hence the result.

Comment: I think we nail down the problem. just want to confirm this: for closures, the position of the outside variable definition doesn't matter, either before or after is ok, as long as it is reachable. Can I safely draw this conclusion?

Comment: Variable position matters in so far as the rules of hoisting and the temporal dead zone matter. Variables declared with `var` are hoisted to the top of the enclosing function and available for use from there (note however that assignment will occur at the lexical position of assignment). `let` and `const` variables are hoisted (I am willing to be corrected on precise terminology here) to the top of the enclosing *block* but not available for use ("temporal dead zone") until their point of lexical declaration. A closure is a reference to a lexical environment and does not affect this behavior.